# Как отличить rvalue от lvalue?

Tags: c++, rvalue

У меня есть некоторый класс A. Мне необходимо сделать функцию func(A a), которая принимает в качестве аргумента lvalue от класса А, но не принимает rvalue от класса A. В случае попытки использовать rvalue класса A - компилятор должен указать на ошибку. Вот пример программы, которая на мой взгляд не должна работать, но компилятор не указывает никакой ошибки. Каким образом - в результате какого правила или какой логики rvalue превращается в lvalue и наделяется адресом? Если это делает какой-то конструктор копирования, можно ли его переопределить? Я пробовал запускать эту программу на Visual Studio 2012, 2019 с опциями Treat Specific Warnings As Error 4238;4239, а также на gcc, но они даже не сообщают о том, что при вызове func, rvalue превращается в lvalue.

```
class A
{   const int value;
public:
    A(const int from_any_type) :value(from_any_type)
    {
    }
};

const A A_rvalue(const A from_any_type)
{   const A a = from_any_type;
    return a; //return as rvalue
}

void func(const A& from_lvalue)
{  //here we get lvalue
    const A* real_address = &from_lvalue;
}

int main()
{
    func(A_rvalue(3));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Нет, не `void func(const A& from_lvalue)`, а `void func(A& from_lvalue)`.

Comment: `func(A && a) = delete;`

Answer (score 3):

Неправильно думать, что у rvalue нет адреса. Компилятор просто не дает его взять, чтобы вам было сложнее отстрелить себе ногу. (Я сейчас не говорю про prvalue, это отдельная мутная тема.)

Если говорить точнее, то объект сам по себе не может быть lvalue или rvalue. Lvalue/rvalue - это свойства *выражения*, т.е. записи в коде, с помощью которой вы обращаетесь к объекту.

Например, если у вас есть `A a;`, то выражение `a` - это lvalue, а выражение `std::move(a)` - это rvalue, хотя они оба обозначают один и тот же объект (у которого, конечно, есть адрес).

---

Ваш код работает потому, что константные lvalue ссылки в виде исключения разрешено инициализировать rvalue.

Можно либо использовать неконстантную ссылку: (но тогда константные lvalue тоже не будут работать)

```
void func(A &from_lvalue) {...}
```

Либо явно запретить вызов на rvalue вот так:

```
void func(const A &from_lvalue) {...}
void func(const A &&) = delete;
```

---

Еще, добавлять `const` при возврате по значению - вредно, потому что это не дает переместить результат, и вынуждает компилятор его копировать.

То же самое с переменной, которую вы отдаете в `return`. Обычно компилятор автоматически делает там перемещение, но с `const` переменной так не получится.

Comment: возврат с `const` это не вредно, а бесполезно, так как возвращаемое значение передаётся компилятору и он сам при копировании объекта теряет свойства `const` и `volatile`. `warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]`

Comment: @AlexGlebe У классов `const` не теряется. Он теряется только у скалярных типов: интов, указателей...

Comment: .. точно `error: no matching function for call to 'SS(const volatile SS)`

Comment: От const избавляться не хотелось бы. Избавиться от них - дело не хитрое. Но концепция программы состоит в том, что все объекты данного класса существуют только в состоянии const от момента создания до уничтожения. Было бы странно, что предоставление дополнительной информации об объектах - const ухудшило бы эффективность компиляции. Неужели есть примеры такого вреда? Идея с удалением `void func(const A &&) = delete;`
мне понятна. Только для MSVC2012 она не работает, там стандарт более ранний C++11. Но я попробовал вместо функции сделать класс, и сделать недоступным вызов секции private:

Comment: @Vadim32 А почему компилятор такой старый? Обновились бы. *"концепция программы состоит в том, что все объекты данного класса существуют только в состоянии const"* Это странно, зачем так? Обычно классы делают так, чтобы их было сложно использовать неправильно, а в вашем случае легко случайно сделать неконстантную копию. *"есть примеры такого вреда?"* Вред в том, что такой объект нельзя переместить, и вместо этого будет происходить более дорогая копия.

Comment: Создание некостантного объекта не представляет  угрозы. Основная угроза в другом. У объектов есть время жизни. Если Obj1 сконcтруирован с помощью Obj2, значит Obj2 создан не позже Obj1 и будет уничтожен после уничтожения Obj1. Obj1 смело может пользоваться данными Obj2 в течение жизни. Но есть ситуация вызова функции.Если Obj3 -это возврат из функции, он создан раньше Obj1, но будет удалён тоже раньше - он временный. Такой возвратный объект можно распознать как rvalue, и Obj1 не может пользоваться данными Obj3 в течение своего существования.Obj1 должен различать временные объекты и постоянные.

Comment: `...
{
  classA Obj1(Obj2);
  // now Obj1 use Obj2
  // Obj2 is permanent
}

{
  classA Obj1(func_Obj3());
   //here result of func_Obj3() is dead
  //Obj1 can not use result of func_Obj3
}
...
`
Про кучу совсем непонятно. По какому праву компилятор может использовать кучу без прямого указания об том в программе. С точки зрения жизни Obj1 при инициализации объект -параметр может быть либо постоянным либо временным, именно об этом речь. И состояние rvalue/lvalue это способ распознать в каком состоянии его конструктор получил объект для инициализации.

Comment: @Vadim32 Все, понял, фигню написал.